# AWS- Set user data for a running instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a running AWS instance. I want to set user-data for this instance.

Question is how do I do it either using AWS console or using AWS CLI tools.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop your instance to change the user-data. The AWS EC2 User Guide has instructions on how to do it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#Using_ChangingAttributesWhileInstanceStopped